# Wordpress - white space margin

Tags: wordpress, whitespace

I've manage to hide the top bar and menu on wordpress page but white space is being displayed on mobile devices at the top of the page.

https://iroae.com/test

I'm using this CSS

```
.page .site-header { 
  display: none;
}

.page .site-top-bar { 
  display: none;
}
```

How can I hide this white space on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your style.css link : [https://iroae.com/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/css/styles.css][css file]

so in your file directory path will be : wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/css/ and file will be style.css

find this:

```css
#page_wrapper.sticky_header {
    padding-top: 50px; }
```

and set padding-top: 0 ;

```css
#page_wrapper.sticky_header {
    padding-top: 0; }
```